# Why did the Bnei Yisrael allow the Geshuri and Machati to stay in Eretz Yisrael (Joshua 13:13)?

Tags: joshua--book-of

Are there any sources explaining why these two peoples were not expelled like so many others?

וְלֹ֤א הוֹרִ֙ישׁוּ֙ בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אֶת־הַגְּשׁוּרִ֖י וְאֶת־הַמַּעֲכָתִ֑י וַיֵּ֨שֶׁב גְּשׁ֤וּר וּמַֽעֲכָת֙ בְּקֶ֣רֶב יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל עַ֖ד הַיּ֥וֹם הַזֶּֽה׃
Nevertheless the children of Israel did not expel the Geshuri, nor the Ma῾akhati: but the Geshuri and the Ma῾akhati dwell amidst Yisra᾽el until this day

Comment: Not just them, other nations stayed in the land as well, such as the Amorites, Philistines and other Canaanite groups. As the verse said, they were unable to fully conquer them. When verses such as this are contrasted with verses that state that a certain tribe dwelled among a non-Israelite group, we learn that when the dwellers amidst are Canaanite, they paid tribute to the Israelites. When the dwellers amidst were Israelites, they paid tribute to the Canaanite. Compare Judges ch. 1 in particular.